# FullScreen picture from webcam

Tags: opencv, webcam, resolution, gldrawpixels

I use openCV to take picture from the cam. Here is code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glTranslatef(0,0,FOCAL_LENGTH);
glRasterPos2d(-width/2,height/2);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glPixelZoom(1.0,-1.0);
glDrawPixels(bg->width, bg->height, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bg->imageData);
```

But when i maximized my window the picture size is only 640*480 - my webcam resolution. And it is only in top left corner of the window. What i must do to match picture size and window size.

Comment: Scale the image to match the size of your window. Or use OpenGL's "fullscreen" mode rather than just maximising your window.

Answer (score 0):

You must resize the image using the cvResize function. Please note this may slow things down a bit depending upon your PC configuration.